# Fontforge: Export a glyph to SVG with fontforge command line

Tags: svg, fontforge

How to export a glyph (from its unicode) to SVG with Fontforge command line ?

I also need to specify the font size and keep the original margins it has in the font.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may have found your answer already, but I just had to do this with the latest build of FontForge. The old answer of this command:

```
fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;' font.ttf
```

From a command prompt didn't want to work on Windows10 (I assume a permission issue), but you could give it a try. A quick work-around is to do it via the GUI Execute Script.

- Run FontForge (For Windows10 installed in the Program Files (x86) directory, you may need to right-click "run_fontforge.exe" --> Run As Administrator).
- Open the font you want to export.
- Go to File > Execute Script
- Paste: `SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;`
- Select "FF" radial button.
- Hit OK

It'll save to the FontForge folder (where run_fontforge.exe is located).

Comment: Thank you Kyle! I am an Ubuntu user and your modification still worked for me. I have Python scripting enabled too but I haven't gotten around to writing a script when this works perfectly well :). Only thing I have to figure out how to do next is to specify the save location for all the svg files.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle K for this answer, helped a lot! have a good day man

Comment: Works great on windows, I just needed to start run_fontforge.exe with Admin permissions.

Comment: On MacOS it extracts it to your user home folder

Comment: On Linux, specifying a destination folder is quite simple. Assuming you have a file "font.ttf" in a specific folder and a subfolder "svg" in which you want to extract all the individual characters, you can use a Bash script of the type: `cd ~/mydir/svg; fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;' ../font.ttf;`

Comment: Is there anyway to select a location for saving the SVGs in Win 10? Also, in Windows, small letters are getting overwritten by cap letters while saving. Any workaround for that?

Comment: @Clicker - i worked around by exporting all characters, moving them to a separate folder, selecting & clearing all uppercase, and running the export again for lowercase.

Comment: @Clicker You can specify a full address as argument to Export, so instead of `Export("svg")` do `Export("/the/path/for/saving/glyph.svg")`.

Comment: @Student Can you please show an example of using a custom path? For some reason it doesn't work for me... It created a single file, and I want a file per each glyph...

Comment: Manually select the glyphs for export (drag mouse to select consecutive, or hold Shift to select non-consecutive), then `File`>`Execute Script`, click **`FF`** radio button, and paste code: `foreach Export("/myDestinationFolder/%n-%e.svg"); endloop;` to export with filenames like `A-65.svg`.

Comment: This will NOT export colored glyphs. Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows os (Tested on win10)

**this is from inside a BATCH file:**

c:\Programs\FontForge\bin\fontforge.exe  -lang=ff -c "Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export('%%e_%%f_%%n_%%u.eps'); endloop;" %1

**this is directly on the command line:**

c:\Programs\FontForge\bin\fontforge.exe  -lang=ff -c "Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export('%e_%f_%n_%u.eps'); endloop;" font-file.ttf

**note** - the color is **not** exported. And I don't know if it's unimplemented, or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

My PowerShell script for Windows 10 (execute from FontForge directory, i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin):

`.\fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export($2); endloop;' 8bitlim.ttf '%n-%e.svg'`

A version that reads all fonts from a subdirectory "fonts" and extracts glyphs:

`$files = Get-ChildItem "fonts"`

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
$infile = "fonts" + $files[$i].Name
.\fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export($2); endloop;' $infile '%n-%e.svg'
}