# FontForge: Export a font's individual glyphs into svg files in batch?

Tags: svg, fonts, fontforge

Is it possible to batch export individual glyphs from a font to SVG without having to export them manually one by one?

Related (but the other way around):
[Import a sequence of .svg files into FontForge as glyphs and output a font file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124130/import-a-sequence-of-svg-files-into-fontforge-as-glyphs-and-output-a-font-file)

Answer (score 7):

Open the font you want to export.

- Go to File > Execute Script
- Paste: SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;
- Select "FF" radial button.
- Hit OK

Also works on the latest Mac version running on Mojave. The font files are saved in you user directory ~./.

Comment: Just for the remark: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127893/), essentially the same for a different question.

Comment: I'm getting a "save failed" error when running this script. Any solution?

Comment: @Clicker make sure you have the font open and loaded. Also, make sure you have the text in correctly, with the correct separators.

Comment: @PeterSuwara Yes, fonts are open and loaded. In fact, I tried with some popular Google Fonts. Getting the same error! Not sure what's causing this. Is there any way to choose a specific save location while running this script? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You need to run the executable as admin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "save failed" error when I first ran the above script. To resolve this problem on Windows 10, I ran FontForge as an Administrator and it ran perfectly fine. All the .svg files will be saved in the same directory where you installed FontForge (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds`). See https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/scripting-alpha.html#Export for documentation on what files are supported when exporting.