# Export a font's individual glyphs into svg files in batch, with unicode name?

Tags: converters, fontforge

I have read and used the instruction given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56179680/1631618) to extract the individual glyphs of a font into separate svg files, but the files' names are not their unicode UTF-8 codes. The number of Glyphs is large and it would be difficult to rename them all by hand accordingly. Is there a way FontForge (*or a similar free application online or on linux*) can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write "%u.svg", instead of "svg".

See the documentation [here](https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/scripting-alpha.html#Export).