# How to convert TTF glyphs to SVG, not appearing in FontForge

Tags: svg, unicode, fonts

I have a TTF file with a bunch of custom glyphs and I want to convert each to SVG. I can view the files just fine on FontDrop

[image]

I can even view the contour data

[image]

But when i open the font in FontForge it doesn't show any glyphs at all.

[image]

Where are these glyphs in this font and how do i access them?

Font is available here:

https://github.com/NetrunnerDB/netrunnerdb-font/blob/master/fonts/netrunner.ttf

Comment: Don't mind not seeing the glyphs immediately, they are just in an area that is not so obvious. For example the one you show above is at codepoint U+E90F, which is in one of the "private use" blocks. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902878 work for you?

Comment: i tried to use that script but i got a continuous loop of errors. had to force exit FontForge

Comment: You might also try opentype.js as described here ["How to convert font icon to .svg by myself?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187756/how-to-convert-font-icon-to-svg-by-myself/75836446#75836446)

Comment: Since I have no problems with the method I linked, it is probably a problem with rights. Make sure you have sufficient rights for writing files - wherever they end up. On Linux, I found them in my home directory, windows seems to choose the fontforge exe folder. I was not able to change the folder with one of the methods mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I have the same issue, this codepen worked for me: https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/XWZGVbZ